# Automake: adding local convenience behavior to "make check"

Tags: testing, makefile, automated-tests, autotools, automake

With a standard project layout of

```
$(src_topdir)/include
$(src_topdir)/src
$(src_topdir)/tests
```

I would like to run all the tests in `$(src_topdir)/tests` when typing "make check" in `$(src_topdir)/src` in addition to running any configured tests in `$(src_topdir)/src`.

Automake provides an extension to add additional targets to the `check` Makefile target, by adding (in Makefile.am) the target `local-check` which I can define to

```
local-check:
        cd ../tests && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) check
```

And while this permits me to `make check` within the `$(src_topdir)/src` directory with satisfaction, unfortunately it breaks the call to `make check` from the `$(src_topdir)` directory.  This is because calling from `$(src_topdir)` recursively enters both `$(src_topdir)/src` and `$(src_topdir)/tests` triggering the tests in `$(src_topdir)/tests` twice.

Is there a way in which I would be able to alter my `Makefile.am` in `$(src_topdir)/src` such that local `make check` calls trigger the desired additional testing while `make check` calls from the rest of the tooling are unaffected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this in Automake.

One workaround is to simply change the name of the target.  That is, instead of typing `make check`, type `make mycheck` (or whatever you like).  Then the `mycheck` rule is very easy to write.

Another idea is to simply dispense with subdirectory Makefiles.  It's generally better, these days, to have one single `Makefile` for the entire tree.  Then this problem goes away -- or, if you really want, with this you can write a tiny `src/Makefile` that just has the single `check` target.

Comment: Thank you.  I've come to more-or-less the same conclusion.  I've a workaround that works for one directory, but fails when the same calls are done from others.  To lessen this impact, I'm mostly adding commands that perform the desired operations from the top level directory.  (top-clean, top-make, top-check) which basically navigate up till the make file is that of the $topdir and then issue the corresponding make target.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is with small Makefiles in the sub-directories that chain to the Automake managed Makefile in the project root directory.

I've managed to get nearly everything I've wanted by using the following Makefile

```
all:
        @make -C .. $@
%:
        @make -C .. $@
```

Basically, the `%:` rule matches everything, calling make in one directory above it.  However, that leaves make without a default rule (as `%:` is a rule pattern).  to correct this issue, I also include an identical rule `all:` which doesn't require rule pattern matching.

In both cases, they call `@make -C .. $@` which calls make, but the `-C ..` says to change the directory to `..` prior to evaluating anything.  Finally the `$@` passes all arguments to the make invocation one directory above.

For this to work well, it means that all builds will be in the root directory `$(src_topdir)`.  This means one needs to modify (in automake systems) the `bin_PROGRAMS` and `{PROGRAM}_SOURCES` to lie in the top level Makefile.am, like so

```
bin_PROGRAMS = src/main

src_main_SOURCES = src/main.c src/module.c
```

Now this will place your `*.o` files in the top level directory, which is undesirable.  To fix that issue, add the `subdir-objects` configuration parameter to your `configure.ac` file, like so:

```
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([subdir-objects ... ])
```

Note the `...` above is not literal, but represents all the other options to `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE`.

With this, one will also have to move the automake test build / configuration into the top level `Makefile.am` but you gain the advantage of being able to type `make check` from the `$(src_topdir)/src` directory, permitting you to verify you don't break unit tests when performing refactoring and other code modifications.